# How do we differentiate Parallel and series network requests using jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have recorded some script using Jmeter and running the same recorded requests multiple times. Meanwhile i got a question like how we can differentiate Parallel and series requests. Because when am taking *aggregate report* for all the network requests it is giving *sum of the requests But Ideally Parallel requests should not sum up*.

So how we can handle this situation,,,**How we will differentiate both parallel and series????**

Answer (score 0):

If you mean AJAX requests by parallel requests, then JMeter can not do that. 
Eventhough your browser makes these requests in parallel,when you run the JMeter script, JMeter will invoke them sequentially only - so it sums up all the requests. It is a limitation of JMeter framework.